# My HTML webpage does not display a scroll bar even though the content cannot be displayed within the browser size

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I am trying to build a basic website with CSS and HTML. I have right now adjusted the code in the following file to shrink the images down to displayable size. But let's suppose i tried decreasing the width of my browser(i am using my laptop) the contents get reorganized and the text moves below the picture as expected. But the problem i am unable to scroll down. I have tried various solutions like setting overflow of html to scroll, setting overflow-x property to hidden in html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-7652187840778484" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <title>
        W3Coders
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="better-style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "topping">
        <h1 style="float: left;color: rgb(58, 118, 209);">W3Coders</h1>
        <h1 style="float: left;margin-left: 870px;color: rgb(58, 118, 209);">Definitely not world's most visited site</h1>
        <img src="images/w3image.png" alt="The Logo" style="float: right; height: 68px;">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="resources.html">Resources</a>
        <a href="skills.html">Skills</a>
        <a href="rate.html">Rate</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contents">
        <img src="images/wwwimage.jpg" alt="Just a picture" style="height: 97%;float: left;">
        <h1>Purpose Of Existence</h1>
        <h4>W3Coders was created for the sole purpose of <s>helping people </s>showcasing my web development skills</h4>
        <h4>It was at this moment i ran out of content to put here. Contact me if you have an idea on what i should do with all the empty space</h4>
        <h1>Random stuff cuz i have idea what do with space:</h1>
        <h4>"Any programmer can write code a computer can understand. It takes skills to write code a person can understand."</h4>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS file:

```
.topping
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 9%;
    color: rgb(92, 84, 84);
    padding: 0%;
}
.navbar{
    background-color: rgb(92,84,84);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;
    position:fixed;
    top:68px;
    left:0px;
}
.people{
    background-color: rgb(58,118,209);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.navbar a{
    float:left;
    color: white;
    padding:14px 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.people a{
    float:left;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.navbar a.active{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(58,118,209);
}
.people a.active{
    background-color:black;
    color: white;
}
.navbar a:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: cyan;
}
.people a:hover{
    color:white;
    background-color: rgb(92, 84, 84);
}
.contents{
    background:url("images/background.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 15%;
    height: 85%;
}
.card{
    background-color: white;
    width: fit-content;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 10px;
    float: left;
    border-color: black;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
h2 .card{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
a img:hover{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: grey;
    border-style: solid;
    animation-name: links;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes links{
    0%{
        border-color: grey;
    }
    25%{
        border-color: red;
    }
    50%{
        border-color: green;
    }
    100%{
        border-color:blue;
    }
}
```

I am using github pages to host my site: https://godofgames0070.github.io
Also, i am using Google Chrome to view my site.

Comment: Your CSS is important to the issue and should be here _**in**_ the question, not somewhere externally where it could disappear or change in the future.

Comment: @StephenP sorry, i have edited to include it now

Answer (score 1):

from the live link I think it will help to amend the below:

//content will be scrollable

```
.contents {
    background: url(images/background.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 15%;
    height: 85%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Navbar looks squeezed too, I have updated the top style, so it fixed and not hidden. Try the below:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: rgb(92,84,84);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 9%;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much Sir. It works now. I tried to upvote but my reputation is too low to publicly display the changes it seems. Thank You very much though

Comment: Also as i said in my question when i added the 'overflow:scroll' to the **html** element it does not work. Do you have any idea why ? Also if you don't mind can you explain why this problem occured to me in the first place ? Thank you very much. Need not reply if you are busy though

Comment: Hi @PeterParker happy it worked well for you. There is no reason why it did not work earlier and works now. It might be that you were trying to add it on img element instead of "contents" div. I have checked your page and its a good start, keep improving it :)  Greta

Answer (score 0):

You're content has a CSS property `position: fixed` applied. You'll need to remove that in order to scroll your content.

If you are looking for a fixed background effect, consider `background-attachment: fixed` instead.

Comment: Hello. I use position:fixed for many elements, where do you want me to try to make the above changes ?

Comment: Well, I removed it from your main "contents" div and that seemed to have a positive effect, so I'd start there. Really, anything you want to have scroll should not have that applied however.

Answer (score -1):

You can put your img in the contents with float: right to start and after reducing the screen using a media query to change the float
something like this :

```
.contents{
   background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 100px;
   height: 85%;
}

.contents>img {
   width: 30%;
   float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  .contents>img {
      width: 100%;
      float: none;
   }  
}
```

Comment: Adding an *optional* end tag won't solve the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This would probably be better as a comment. It doesn't solve the issue so it shouldn't be an answer.

Comment: sorry for my first comment! I post a new solution